# Using float when using margin:0 auto;

Tags: css, css-float

Im using

```
margin:0 auto;
```

in a Div

Inside that Div is another Div that has

```
float:left;
width:850px;
```

Where does the 850px start from on the webpage?  In the center outwards?

Comment: **margin: 0 auto** work with fixed width. To learn more about HTML & CSS CHECK this http://www.htmldog.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed

Comment: Feel free to check out the [css-float tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-float/info) for some basic information on how they work.

Answer (score 1):

The inner div will be placed at the left edge of the outer div. The outer div will be centered according to the the width that you have specified for it.

If you haven't specified any with for the outer element, it will use the default width `auto`, which will make it use all the available width, and it won't appear centered at all as there are no margins left on the sides. In that case the inner div will start at the left edge of the body (i.e. inside the body margin/padding).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/34ES3/